# Register a LUA script to be triggered when a specified (redis-key, op) event occurs

Tags: triggers, lua, redis

Can I make a LUA script to be a *TRIGGER* used in relational database. 
e.g., after ever append or rpush to the list with key 'TIMELIST', a lua script is triggered to do some work on the list?

I have a quick look at the lua-script section in REDIS documentation and found that it seems that the script can only be explicitly evaluated. Is my idea impossible?

EXT:
If the above idea is impossible. What I should take to address such problem. I have a sorted list to store daily quotas. I use

```
> ZADD 'TIMELIST' <TS> <QUOTA>
```

to add a new a quota with its date as the weight. I wanna the sorted list act as a bounded list which only maintain the last 7 days' quotas. I don't use the LTRIM on a normal redis-list because the quotas may have *gap* in timeline. Hash isn't suitable either since for some reason, I must make the TRUNCATION op invisible to application who access REDIS.

I'm a newbie to redis. Any suggestion? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

No, that isn't doable. What you can easily do, however, is use a script to both perform the operation (`LPUSH`, `ZADD`, etc) as well as any additional trigger-like logic.

Comment: Thanks. Seem that your advice is the only way

Comment: For the time being, it is.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [ZREMRANGEBYRANK](https://redis.io/commands/zremrangebyrank) to remove the old elements.

```
redis> ZADD myzset 1 "one"
(integer) 1
redis> ZADD myzset 2 "two"
(integer) 1
redis> ZADD myzset 3 "three"
(integer) 1
redis> ZREMRANGEBYRANK myzset 0 1
(integer) 2
redis> ZRANGE myzset 0 -1 WITHSCORES
1) "three"
2) "3"
redis>
```

Answer (score 0):

There has been an interesting development with Redis regarding these kind of "triggers". You could accomplish what you want with:
Redis Key Space Notifications (get notified when an event happens - for example adding a key to your set/zset) and run an internal Redis Module (new in Version 5)
that will perform a ZREM from set under some conditions - effectively having a Redis "trigger".

You could technically just use the Key Space Notifications option that send a pub/sub event (in Redis) - but you might miss events if you have no subscribers to that event (pub/sub events in Redis are not durable).

The downside is that you will have to write that module in C/C++ code and validate it works properly.